# Getting the following: "General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint" for table users where no fk constraint is specified in that table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, migration

So I was using homestead to have a database (actually 2 databases) inside my Laravel project, everything was working just fine, untill I decided to add Laravel Jetstream in my project. I followed the [documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html) and ran couple commands (npm init/php artisan jetstream:install livewire etc...) like it's described in the documentation.

But now with the new Jetstream/Livewire migrations, when I'm running php artisan migrate:fresh I'm getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
> constraint (SQL: create table `users` (`id` char(36) not null, `name`
> varchar(255) not null, `email` varchar(255) not null,
> `email_verified_at` timestamp null, `password`  varchar(255) not null,
> `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null,
> `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
> 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

I noticed that if I change the table's name to anything but "users" the migration works just fine (even "user" works) and I can migrate it, but it seems that I can't use the name "users" for my table....

Why? and why am I suddenly getting this error? I don't even have aforeign key in my table.

2014_10_12_100001_create_users_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

EDIT:

After adding

> Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

I now have some more details on the error and I figured the problem came from another migration:

> General error: 1822 Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
> index for constraint 'folders_owner_id_foreign' in the referenced
> table 'users'

This references a foreign key constraint that I have on the other database I'm using on my project, that has a foreign key constraint referencing my users.id field.

The migration I'm talking about:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('folders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string("name");
            $table->foreignUuid("owner_id")->references("id")->on("ceerco.users");
            $table->string("organisation_id");
            $table->string("organisation_type");
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('folders');
    }
};
```

By just dropping the table on the other database, and rerunning all the migrations, everything now works fine... I still don't know why it rose an issue now that I installed Jetstream, because before that, everytime I used my migrate fresh command, I didnt have any SQL error.

Comment: For more details: I already had a users table before i used Jestream and added all the files with npm init and all the required commands to nstall Jetstream

Answer (score 0):

Never used JetStream but try to dd somewhere in the migration this line to check if it has a foreign key:

```
(Schema::hasForeign($table, $foreignKeyName))
```

or

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: I tried to add  Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();  now I'm getting a similar error but with some more details I edited the question, but there is progress